# Disable When you follow this site you'll get updates in your newsfeed message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I disable the following message. Users receive this message when they access the site:

[image]

This is for Sharepoint 2013 on prem.

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't an answer yet, I'll propose one:

When the url ends with: `?FollowSite=1&SiteName=[displayed site name]`, it will open this message.